# Java 21 Support for Spring Boot 2.7

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-21

I know the current development path is to support Java 21 on Spring Boot 3.2, and that is supposed to be released around the end of November 2023.

Is there a timeline for Java 21 support for Spring Boot 2.7?

Even a snapshot of 2.7 that supports 21 would be useful as it would allow us to test our code on 21.

We would like to move to Java 21 as soon as it's available, but are uncertain about the timeline of 2.7 support.

Comment: [spring-boot issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) should be the right place to seek that support.

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade your project to Spring Boot 3. Spring Boot 2.7 reaches end of public support on 2023-11-18. See https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

Comment: What do you mean with support for java21? Have you tried to run your Spring Boot application with Java21 already? Spring 5.3 supports java21, as Spring Boot 2.7 uses Spring 5.3 it will probably just work (but I would suggest to test it). See also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35790

Comment: @TomStroemer I'm working on a very large application that will require a significant amount of work to transition from Boot 2.7 to Boot 3.x.  The move to Java 21 will be a much quicker win but we do plan on migrating to Boot 3.x when we can.

Comment: @M.Deinum it looks like 2.7.16 will support JDK 21 explicitly.  Looking at the Spring Boot source code (2.7 branch) the JavaVersion.java now contains 21, whereas just days ago it didn't, and it specifically references "since 2.7.16" in the javadoc.

Comment: I dont think they will add it , since boot 2 series will be  reaching end of life as of 2023 November. 2.7.16 is released as of today (after one day of java 21 release) and there is no mention.

Comment: Try running it with Java 21 and see what happens?

Comment: The documentation for 2.7.17 has been updated to include Java 21: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37371

Answer (score 0):

Java 21 should support springboot 2.5+ versions, if not please upgrade your springboot version to 3.x.